# How to define date formate for xforms:input control

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I have the following date control and binding for date picker.
It always show the date format in mm/dd/yyyy.
But i want to display in mmm/dd/yyyy format in screen

```
<xforms:bind id="effective-date" nodeset="instance('account')/transcation-date/effective-date" type="xforms:date" />

<xforms:input bind="effective-date" >
</xforms:input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only these [documented date formats](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-xforms#TOC-For-xforms%3ainput-) are supported for the `<xforms:input>`. In the future, Orbeon Forms might implement this in a more generic way, so a wider range of dates formats pictures can be supported.